# How do I calculate how long it will take for a capacitor to discharge when shorted?

Tags: capacitor, math

If I know the capacitance, series resistance, and the voltage it is charged to. I tried using a graph y=x/0.003
Where y is current and x is voltage, but now i'm lost, because I don't know where to put the capacitance. And then I wouldn't know how to get time.

Comment: Shorting a capacitor takes zero time to discharge. It also produces a mean spike of current and may generate a flash when doing so.

Comment: Ideally, it will decrease exponentially and never quite get to zero.

Comment: You also need to know the type of capacitor. If it's a type prone to dielectric relaxation, you can discharge to 0V, disconnect the load, and watch the voltage recover anything up to 15% of the original. (15% for electrolytics according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_absorption )

Comment: @BrianDrummond And if it was charged to a high voltage, what happens next could shock you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discharge equation is:

\$V_c = V_0\cdot e^{\frac{-t}{R\cdot C}}\$

If this is re-arranged to isolate t:

\$t = -R\cdot C \cdot ln(\frac{V_c}{V_0}) \$

if R is a true short and there is no series resistance then the capacitor will instantly discharge (with infinite current). In a real-world situation with a finite resistance it will discharge "quickly" with an exponential characteristic

use python/excel/calculator and plug your numbers in but use something like 1e-6 for the final capacitor voltage Vc

Comment: To clarify this response (which actually answered the question), V0 is the initial voltage on the capacitor before the resistor is connected, and Vc is the capacitor voltage after it has been discharging for time t.  Also, the 0 in V0 is a zero, not an "o".  This term stands for the capacitor voltage at time = 0, the moment the resistor is connected.

Comment: I used this formula to get the time it would get to a voltage that 1 last extra electron would have. Then in a separate equation I used the elementary charge, divided it by the 1 electron voltage divided by the resistance, and got a time that was around 2-1/e of the time of the penultimate electron, or R*C. Is it okay to add RC into the equation aswell?